Remove spaces between specific words
I have the following output
ssh-rsa aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccc ddddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee mail: email@email.com

I wanted to remove all spaces between ssh-rsa and mail:
So I will get this result
ssh-rsa aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee mail: email@email.com


You wanted it? What exactly have prevented you from getting the desired result?

you probably wanted something like awk '{print$1,$2$3$4$5$6,$7,$8}'

Will "mail:" always be the 2nd-last word?

Pipe the output to awk. Since you haven't specified that the number of spaces will always be the same, you can generically remove spaces between the 2nd and before the antipenultimate (last but two, e.g. next before next to last) fields using:
awk '{for (i=2; i<NF-1; i++) s = s $i; print $1,s,$(NF-1),$NF}'

Above the 2nd field through the antipenultimate are concatenated in the variable s. To get the desired result, the first and last two fields are then added with the concatenated string in the middle.
(note: if the number of fields never changes, you can simplify the awk statement to what @Fravadona posted in the comment)
Example Use/Result
$ echo "ssh-rsa aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccc ddddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee mail: email@email.com" | 
awk '{for (i=2; i<NF-1; i++) s = s $i; print $1,s,$(NF-1),$NF}'
ssh-rsa aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee mail: email@email.com


Tricky bit of perl:
perl -pe 's/(?<=ssh-rsa )(.+)(?= mail)/ ($str = $1) =~ s{ }{}g; $str /e'

$ echo "$line" | perl -pe 's/(?<=ssh-rsa )(.+)(?= mail)/ ($str = $1) =~ s{ }{}g; $str /e'
ssh-rsa aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee mail: email@email.com


Here is an approach using regular expression matching in Bash, accessing the capture groups in the BASH_REMATCH array:
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    if [[ $line =~ ^(ssh-rsa )(.*)( mail:.*) ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]// /}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    fi
done

This uses the //pattern/replacement form of Bash parameter expansion to remove all spaces.
